# how can we set master wallet for sending funds to our application users through it in solidity?

Tags: solidity, ethereum-wallet-dapp

Is it possible to set master wallet for contract when user wins then contract send funds from master wallet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the master wallet would be the contract itself you would need a function like this (assuming there is another function getting this funds):

```
function sendFunds(address winner) public {
//This sends all the funds inside the contract
   payable(address).transfer(address(this).balance);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @julissa DC What if i want to transfer the NFT from my Master Wallet using tokenIds?

Comment: Would the NFT would be already minted or will it mint on this step?

Comment: its already minted and its inside the wallet

Comment: Julissa can you please tell me?

Comment: Before entering the function call the `approve` method from the contract to the winner, and inside the function include a `transferFrom` call